# Why iTextSharp NuGet doesn't works correctly from installed C# program?

Tags: c#, wpf, installation, itext

I am using iTextSharp NuGet Package to generate PDF files from my C# program. When I runnning the program from the Debugger, the PDF generating works correctly, but after I create installer from my project and install it on Windows, the generating is not working. After I start the PDF generating, the program is closes.

I thought the problem was that the NuGet package files did not exists in the installer, but the instalker contains the .dll file of iTextSharp NuGet. I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects to create the installer.

The program stops at the PDF_writer in the constructor, the error is System.NullReferenceException. The file path is from a SaveFileDialog.

My code is here:

```
internal class PDF_generate
    {
        Document PDF_document;
        PdfWriter PDF_writer;
        Font boldFont;

        DbConnect dbConnect;

        public PDF_generate(string filePath)
        {
            PDF_document = new Document(PageSize.A4);

            try
            {
                PDF_writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(PDF_document, new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create));
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            boldFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Times New Roman", 26, Font.BOLD);

            dbConnect = new DbConnect("127.0.0.1", "coinamy_db", "root", "");
        }

        public bool Connect()
        {
            try
            {
                PDF_document.Open();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public bool Connect_Close()
        {
            try
            {
                PDF_document.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void GenerateDocument()
        {
            if (Connect())
            {
                PDF_document.AddAuthor("CoinAmy"); 

                string imageURL = @"..\..\Images\coinamy_logo_original.png"; 
                Image image = Image.GetInstance(imageURL);
                image.ScalePercent(15f); 
                PDF_document.Add(image); 

                PDF_document.Add(new Paragraph("Portfolio", boldFont) 
                {
                    Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER,
                    SpacingAfter = 20,
                });

                PdfPTable investmentsTable = new PdfPTable(6);

                investmentsTable = dbConnect.LoadDataToExport();
                investmentsTable.WidthPercentage = 100;

                PDF_document.Add(investmentsTable);

                PDF_document.Add(new Paragraph($"Export date: {DateTime.Now}")
                {
                    Alignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT,
                    SpacingBefore = 20
                });

                Connect_Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't iTextSharp require a license file or similar?

Comment: No, as I see iTextSharp is an AGPL software.

Comment: Please apply logging to find out on which line your program stops. And show your code.

Comment: @mkl I've added my source code and the problem to my question.

Comment: Please also share the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: @mkl Sorry for the late reply. The exception is: 'CoinAmy.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: CoinAmy.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\***\Desktop\CoinAmy\CoinAmy\bin\Release\itextsharp.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in itextsharp.dll

Comment: Can you supply some stack trace to the point of code that error happened at?

Comment: @mkl I put the line on which VS throws an exception (PDF_writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(PDF_document, new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create));) into a try-catch, but this exception handler doesn't even catch the exception. If I click on the green triangle for the errors thrown up by VS, it generates the document successfully in the end, but after the exceptions.

Comment: @mkl The stack trace is:  at iTextSharp.text.Version.GetInstance()

Comment: `Version.GetInstance()` catches most of its possible exceptions itself.

Comment: I assume the exception you see in vs is a different one than the one causing the issue in the installed release.

Comment: If the "Just my code" function is turned on in VS, it does not throw an exception at all when running in VS, however, if I run the installed program, the problem also exists and the application stops. If this exception is not the error, then our other exception should also appear in VS when running.